# Cannot empty trash after deleting .dmg

Tags: macos, applications, dmg

So, I downloaded Chrome, and I put it in the Applications folder and from there a shortcut to the applications bar on the bottom of the screen. All is fine, but now there's an icon on the desktop that looks like a harddrive with a Chrome icon on it. I don't want it there, but I don't know what to do with it. I also have the DMG file from the download in the Trash, but it won't let me delete it.

So, **how do I get rid of the downloaded file** which I thought was 'installed' in the Applications folder?
Also, **how do I get rid of the Chrome HDD icon on the desktop**.
And, in the end **how many copies of an application does OS X keep just to make it work**? It's rather annoying coming from Windows, where there's only one...

Anyway, help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Alex you have 2 options. 1) Right click on 'Hard drive icon" and Click on "Eject" OR 2) open finder and you can see an 'eject' icon next to your Chrome HDD icon.

Comment: For your other questions which will come, and as it's easier to search when you have the right terms, the "applications bar on the bottom of the screen" is called the Dock. Take your time to wander in the preference panes and come back to us with your questions.

Comment: @Alex: like LudoMC said, if you play around with the system preferences, you'll be understanding things in no time.  Pretty soon you'll be hooked like the rest of us :)

Comment: I can recommend the 'How To' videos of the common Mac features at http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/ plus time spent in a larger Apple Store that has seminars is worth it.

Comment: @Alex Can you make these each separate questions?

Comment: Alex, please consider opening new questions instead of just adding on to this one (and welcome!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hard-drive looking thing on the desktop is a mounted disk image; the .dmg file is the file where the data for the image is.

To get rid of the image, unmount it. There are <strike>three four</strike> five good ways to do it:

1. Drag the disk to the trash. The trash will turn into an eject icon while dragging.
2. Highlight the disk on the desktop and select File > Eject in the Finder menu bar.
3. Highlight the disk on the desktop and press Command-E.
4. In any Finder window, press the Eject button next to the disk in the sidebar.
5. Right-click (or control-click or two-finger-click) on the icon and select Eject. (from JoshHibschman in the comments below)
6. You can also eject from the commandline using `diskutil` if you really want.

After you eject the disk

Insofar as the application "file" is concerned, there is only one copy of the application: the one in the /Applications folder. The icon in the dock is only a link (not really a shortcut, as there's no file like a shortcut in the Start menu or the Quick Launch bar, but it's not bad to think of the Dock icon as a "shortcut".)

And to answer your first question, this is a great place to come with questions. Hope you have a good time on the Mac!

Comment: Hah, beat me to it!

Comment: Ahh, I see, so, do I have to first 'eject' the HDD before I can delete the DMG? All this after the app has been placed in the Applications folder...

Comment: 6. Right-click (two finger tap) > Eject  -- just for completion :D

Comment: You should be able to move the .dmg to the Trash before ejecting if you want, but you'll have to eject the mounted disk before you empty the trash.

Comment: @Josh: I always forget about the right-click options. :)

Comment: @CajunLuke, okay, that's why it was yelling at me. I didn't have the mounted disk ejected first. Speaking of disk, where do I go to see the HDD space?

Comment: Do a "Get Info" on your hard drive. (Command-I or File > Get Info) That'll show you total, used, and free.

Comment: Aha! Found it. So, 'Get Info' is essentially the same as 'Properties' in Windows?

Comment: Essentially, yes. There's not much you can edit in Get Info, though. Certainly not to the extent you can in Windows.