# All of a sudden, I can't empty my trash. At all. What now?

Tags: macos, trash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emptying the Trash: not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43757/emptying-the-trash-not-working)

Title mostly says it all. Nothing about my system has really changed that I can think of. I've been running Lion since shortly after its release, and I'm up to date on software updates.

I've restarted multiple times. I've done a permissions repair in disk utility. I can continue to put things in the trash, but I can't empty it. I've tried option-clicking the empty trash menu item (to skip the confirmation) as well as not doing that. Same result.

Every time, it just sits here:

[image: can't empty my trash! :(]

Clicking the <kbd>X</kbd> icon to cancel the operation doesn't close it, either. The only way to get the window to go away is to kill/relaunch finder.

I'm worried that the SSD is about to die -- but I haven't had any other warning signs. Fortunately I'm pretty good about backups. Between Time Machine and source control repos, I shouldn't lose anything if it were to die, but my free year of AppleCare is over very soon, so I want to get it addressed if it is a hardware issue.

Any advice?

Comment: Have a look at the site search. Here are but three of the questions and answers we have on this already. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43757/emptying-the-trash-not-working http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6879/cannot-empty-trash-after-deleting-dmg http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40212/cannot-empty-trash

Comment: If they don't answer your question, just edit your question to make it different than the questions already asked (perhaps linking to the closest question and explaining why the answers there don't work for you. Then flag this for re-opening if needed.

Comment: Would you add a comment or fix up the linked question that addressed your issue to improve it - make it more general?

Comment: I think the thread is general enough, I just, embarrassingly, didn't search here before posting. (Though I did google it.)

Comment: OK - thanks for the input - I can't wait to see more questions and answers from you. No worries - only the moderators will see this after a while and _everyone_ gets questions closed - especially the first 10 or so.